Nextjs file uploading useState not working
Can someone help me to fix this? I couldn't set 'previews' to my 'imagePreview'. it still shows empty array []

"use client";
import Image from "next/image";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const FileUploder = () => {
  const [imagePreviews, setImagePreviews] = useState([]);

  function handleFileUpload(e) {
    const files = e.target.files;
    console.log(files);
    const previews = Array.from(files).map((file) => URL.createObjectURL(file));
    setImagePreviews(previews);
    console.log(imagePreviews);
  }


I have used file upload component in one of my nextjs application. You can refer to below code :-
"use client";
import Image from "next/image";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const FileUploder = () => {
  const [imagePreviews, setImagePreviews] = useState([]);

  function handleFileUpload(e) {
    const files = e.target.files;
    console.log(files);

    // Create an empty array to store the previews
    const previews = [];

    // Loop through each file and create an object URL for it
    for (const file of files) {
      previews.push(URL.createObjectURL(file));
    }

    // Update the imagePreviews state with the new previews array
    setImagePreviews(previews);
    console.log(imagePreviews); // This should now show the object URLs
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" multiple onChange={handleFileUpload} />
      {imagePreviews.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          {imagePreviews.map((preview) => (
            <Image key={preview} src={preview} alt="" width={200} height={200} /> // Assuming you want to display the images
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FileUploder;

Let me know if this works or not.

I was doing the exact same thing. But imagePreviews state is not updating with the new 'preview' object. I got stucked.

Because of the asynchronous nature of useState hook, the state gets update after some time.
setImagePreviews(previews);
console.log(imagePreviews);

Hence you will find not updated empty array in console.log(). You can read more about it
here
